# A function $f(t)\in\mathcal{C}^r$ implies that $f^{(r+1)}(t)$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, continuity

I have a doubt about $r$-times continously differentiable functions. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. If $f\in\mathcal{C}^r$, then, can we conclude something about $f^{(r+1)}(t)$?.

Obviously, if $f(t)\in\mathcal{C}^r$, then $f^{(r)}(t)$ exists and it is continous. Does it imply that $f^{(r+1)}(t)$ also exist and it is Lebesgue integrable?.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the function
$$
f(t)=\max(t^3,0).
$$

Answer (score 1):

No:integrate $r$ times the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) (which is continuous but not derivable) to obtain a counterexample to  the existence of the $r+1$ derivative.

One may now wonder wether the existence of the derivative is a sufficient condition for its lebesgue integrability: the answer is still no. Take the integral of $x^2\sin(x^{-2})$. This function is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$, but its $2$-nd derivative, i.e. the derivative of $x^2\sin(x^{-2})$ is not integrable around $0$.